# Grial nuget package breaks build on mobile.azure.com

Tags: azure, xamarin, nuget-package

I recently added grial nuget packages to a xamarin solution.
It works fine locally but the build fails on mobile.azure.com.

I have used the nuget command line to add the new package source, including the credentials as a username / encrypted password.
It still breaks the build though, but this time with the error 
"Data unprotection failed."

Has anyone come across this before, and do you have any possible solution?

thanks

Comment: Could you share the complete build log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider adding a nuget.config file. Below is an example that we used to include our Proget Feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
     <add key="enabled" value="true" />
     <add key="automatic" value="true" />
  </packageRestore>
<packageSources>
  <add key="NRTH Proget" value="http://proget.nrth.com/nuget/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Just drop this file in the same folder as your solution (.sln) file.